# An extension of Helly's theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, convex-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let $A ⊂ \Bbb R^2$ be a fixed convex set and let $X_1, \cdots , X_n ⊂ \Bbb R^2$ be any convex sets such that every three of them intersect a translation of $A$. Then there exists a translation of $A$ that intersects all sets $X_i$.

The proof of the same is given as follows:

[image]

So what I have understood is this as given below:
[image]

But how did they assume that $Y_i$ is a convex set? Don't we have to prove that it is a convex set? I want to know how to prove $Y_i$ as convex set.

Comment: Can you break down what you understand of the proof thus far? At which point are you stuck, and what do you understand of the sentence before it?

Comment: This seems to be a straightforward proof (which yes, you have to fill in some of the details), so knowing where you're stuck would be extremely helpful (in addition to "show your work").

Comment: FWIW This setup is quite "standard" (for wanting to apply Kelly), and it was how I solved this problem when you posted it a week ago.

Comment: @CalvinLin I have now understood the problem. Beforehand I got stuck with the diagram and was not able to make sense of the diagram.

Comment: @CalvinLin But I did not understand how did they take Yi as a convex set? do not we have to prove it?

Comment: Right, you have to prove that $Y_i$ is still a convex sex, which they have skipped. This can be done by thinking of $Y_i$ as the "addition" of 2 convex sets. It's possible that your textbook has done this perviously, which is why they skipped a step here. If you're stuck on how to prove this rigorously, write out what you've tried.

Comment: @calvinlin I am quite comfortable in proving addition of two convex sets is convex. But one doubt that I have is ..when you say that Y_i is formed by addition of two convex sets which convex sets are you referring to.  Do you mean addition of A' and X_i because that's the only two convex sets I'm seeing that is mentioned.

Comment: Yes. I believe that $Y_i = X_i + (-A)$, where the origin is taken as the CM of A. You can see this from the drawing, taking "x_i + boundary of A to CM of A". (actually, any fixed point of A will work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**i)** If $a$ is *any interior point* in the triangle
$A$, then $A'$ is a translations and $a'$ is a
corresponding point (We also use the notation $A''$ for translations)

Fix a *line segment* $[pq]$ Then define $D_{[pq]}^A = \bigcup_{a'\in
[pq]}\
 A'$

That is, we can view $D_{pq}^A$ as a trajectory when we push $A$
along $[pq]$. Hence the set is *convex*.

If $a'=p,\ a''=q$ and $A'\bigcap A''$ is nonempty, then

> *the
> intersection is in any translation in* $D_{[pq]}^A$.

**ii)** Fix a point $r$ so that we define
$$ R = \bigg\{ a' \bigg| A'\bigcap \{r\} \neq \emptyset \bigg\} $$

If $a',\ a''\in R$, then $[a'a'']$ is in $R$ by step i) so that $R$
is a *convex set*.

**iii)** When $X$ is a convex set, we define $Y = \bigcup_{p\in X}\ P$.

> If $p,\ q\in X$, then $D_{[pq]}^R$ is contained in $Y$ so that $Y$
> is *convex*

Here note that $Y$ coincides to the set defined in OP.